# Completely different render image from viewport Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

Hello below I have what is supposed to be the rendered image, and the second image is what is being rendered. I am not sure why this is happening, assuming a certain setting in my render properties. But, I can't seem to figure it out. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I ended up figuring it out! I had my displacement modifier set to view in render but not viewport. just in case anyone else has an issue!

Comment: Ok I was wondering if it was that or a Displacement node, you can answer to yourself actually

Answer (score 0):

My displacement modifier was set to only show in render instead of viewport.